# IcCube - Treefilter without scrollbar and with only limited number of elements

Tags: filter, tree, iccube

We try to use the treefilter in IcCube to show categories with subcategories. Now we discovered two problems, we don't know, how to fix:

1. We have 15 categories on level 1, but only the first 11 of them show. There is some space underneath, so it doesn't seem to be cut due to rendering:

[image]

2. We are not able to activate a vertical scrollbar, so when we unfold the tree, there are parts we cannot see anymore. The hotizontal scrollbar is there, but once the tree is too big (image 2) it can't be used anymore as well.

[image]

Did we do something wrong and there are options we didn't see, or are our problems due to some bugs in this widget?

Comment: Can you add the version of the reporting to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 1)
Try to increase `Max Member Count` property on the `Query Wizard` tab of the widget (this number is for all the members to be managed, not only level 1 items)

Point 2)
Try adding `{"cssStyle":"overflow:auto"}` in the `Content CSS` property of the `Box` tab of the widget.

Comment: As Bertrand mentioned the CSS is wrong; has been fixed in the latest release as following:  .ic3-filter-tree {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  ul.dynatree-container {
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    overflow: initial;

    .dynatree-title {
      color: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    span.dynatree-selected .dynatree-title {
      color: inherit;
      font-style: inherit;

    }
  }
}

Comment: We use version 5.1.6, which still seems to be the newest. Bertrand solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ulrich, fixed in the coming 5.1.7